# how to Stop the rounding of numbers inside the ms access db?

Tags: ms-access, rounding

Can anyone can help to Stop the rounding of number inside the ms access db.
in field size:i put decimal still its getting rounded.
I am taking some data's from excel to db but after filling the db the decimal values getting automatically rounded.
I need to stop that.

Answer (score 2):

as can be seen in the Microsoft community forums this can be adjusted in the properties area of the table design:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/turning-off-rounding-on-access-2010/60e825d5-ccb2-4af4-83e5-55ba4e6ab39a

Open the table in design view.
Select the number field.
Look at the field properties in the lower part of the table design window.
If the Field Size property is set to Long Integer, Integer or Byte, it can only contain whole numbers. In order to be able to enter decimals, the Field Size must be Single or (preferably) Double.
If it is already set to Single or Double, look at the Format property. If this is set to Fixed, and Decimal Places is set to 0, the field can contain decimals, but all values will be displayed as whole numbers.